# Android: How publish H264 raw data to live stream server via RTMP

Tags: android, h.264, rtmp, live-streaming, dji-sdk

I would like live stream video from Drone to Wowza Streaming Engine Server. I got `H264` raw data from [this callback](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/android/reference/dji/sdk/camera/DJICamera.CameraReceivedVideoDataCallback.html), And I'm looking a library which supports live stream from `H264` raw data or any document about live stream from H264 data.
Thank for any support.

Answer (score 0):

DJI released a new version of the SDK 4.0, where it comes with an [example](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample) of how to decode that raw data into YUV image using FFMpeg.

Folowing that example, you can modify this method

```
 private void screenShot(byte[] buf, String shotDir) {

      YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(buf,
                 ImageFormat.NV21,
                 DJIVideoStreamDecoder.getInstance().width,
                 DJIVideoStreamDecoder.getInstance().height,
                 null);

 //you can therefore stream it to your Wowza Server

 }
```

I don't know what are your objectives. However, I'd sugest you to encode that YUV frame to Jpeg, and transmit it throught UDP, like a Peer to Peer application.

[Here](https://github.com/raullalves/p2p-video-streaming-udp-opencv) is a simple way of how to stream live video using UDP. It uses C++, but is simple to understand